# ERROR: Fetch failed! HTTP response: 503 Service Unavailable [503 Service Unavailable]

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm trying fetch file from remote server using url.

**CODE:**

```
use File::Fetch;
use strict;

my $url = 'http://***********/all-bin/ASNvx14173/JAKASUSI_BUP_IIR009.doc';
$ENV{HTTP_proxy}=$proxy_url;
my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url);
my $where = $ff->fetch(to => "/temp");
my $file = $ff->file;
my $error=$ff->error();
    print "result=$error\n";
    print "Error==>$url==>$error\n";
    if($error){
    $logger->error("Not fetching attachments!! - $error\n FILE  $id : $url\n");
    }
    next if ( $error ne "" );
    delete $ENV{HTTP_proxy};
```

**ERROR**

```
Fetch failed! HTTP response: 503 Service Unavailable [503 Service Unavailable] at ./bin/convert_to_csv.pl line 911 thread 1.
Fetch failed! HTTP response: 503 [Service Unavailable] at ./bin/convert_to_csv.pl line 911 thread 1.
```

I'm not able to handle this error. And also how to set timeout for particular file to fetch? please help me how to handle it.

Comment: What is line 911 of ./bin/convert_to_csv.pl ?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/File-Fetch-0.48/lib/File/Fetch.pm) has the documentation for File::Fetch.

Look at [this](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/File-Fetch-0.48/lib/File/Fetch.pm#%24where_=_%24ff-%3Efetch%28_%5Bto_=%3E_/my/output/dir/_%7C_%5C%24scalar%5D_%29).

> Returns the full path to the downloaded file on success, and false on
>   failure.

You'll need to check where for false to see if there was an issue.

```
my $where = $ff->fetch(to => "/temp");
if ( !$where ) {
    my $error=$ff->error();
    print "result=$error\n";
    print "Error==>$url==>$error\n";
    $logger->error("Not fetching attachments!! - $error\n FILE  $id : $url\n");
}
else {
    my $file = $ff->file;
    # do stuff with file
}
```

Also [this](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/File-Fetch-0.48/lib/File/Fetch.pm#%24File%3a%3aFetch%3a%3aTIMEOUT) explains setting TIMEOUT to a value.  `$File::Fetch::TIMEOUT = $value_in_seconds;`